# TextBox.Text Changing Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm updating a LINQ object prior to SubmitChanges.  The values of the object's properties are being taken from a series of TextBoxes.

When I read in one specific TextBox, another TextBox changes its value with no apparent cause.

```
//...
loc.Lattitude = txtLocLat.Text; // txtLocLong.Text changes to previous value
loc.Longitude = txtLocLong.Text; // Which is now the previous value
dc.SubmitChanges();
// ...
```

As a result, loc.Longitude never gets updated with the user input. Why would it do this?

- The TextBoxes have no databindings
- The TextBoxes have no events defined
- Breakpointing into the first line merely steps through the DataContext's loc.Lattitude setter.

Comment: Is this asp.net, silverlight, WPF or winforms?

Comment: Sorry 'bout that - Winforms; .NET 3.5.

Comment: You spelled latitude wrong.  You sure no databinding is going on in any of the controls on the page?  No event handlers are defined that you don't know about?

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo I made when I built the database; but the DBML matches the typo so it works out.

I wrote the whole app myself so I know what does what. These TextBoxes were just added today and there's nothing that goes through and finds controls dynamically, etc etc.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the txtLocLong TextChanged event and see if the stack trace is any help.

Comment: OK, added a txtLocLong_TextChanged() and looked. Nothing between that and the form loader, and sure enough. The TBs are updated by the SelectedIndexChanged of a related ListBox, and the Lat setter causes the databound listbox to refresh, which fires off the Loc getter in the middle of a setter. 

So go ahead and stick that in an answer so I can mark it up; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a breakpoint on the txtLocLong TextChanged event and see if the stack trace is any help.